# How do I use dynamic segments in EmberJS' 2.2 router?

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

I can't figure out how to create routes with dynamic segments in the new router API for EmberJS. I've spent a week on it and tried many things but it doesn't work. I am really frustrated at myself because I've gone through the docs, API and source code many times and cannot figure out how to make this work. I am dying for assistance.

I am trying to achieve the following routes:

- /profile/:userId -> index
- /profile/:userId/activity -> activity page
- /profile/:userId/...

My router is set up like this

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  return this.resource("profile", function() {
    this.route("index", { path: '/:userId' });
    this.route("activity", { path: '/:userId/activity' });
  });
});
```

Then, whenever I try to link with the `linkTo` helper, I receive the following error: `Uncaught More objects were passed than dynamic segments`

```
<li>{{#linkTo "profile.index" user}}overview{{/linkTo}}</li>
```

If I don't include the `user` object, then I receive another error `Uncaught Error: assertion failed: Cannot call get with 'id' on an undefined object.` (obviously because there's no object to take the ID of)

If it's any helper, here are my route declarations

```
App.ProfileIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return Ember.Object.create({
      id: 1
    });
  },
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    return controller.set("content", model);
  }
});

App.ProfileActivityRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return Ember.Object.create({
      id: 1
    });
  },
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    return controller.set("content", model);
  }
});
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the segments from: /:userId' to: /:user_id'. Ember uses underscores not camelCase it it's defaults for route segments.

Comment: Also,  
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
    return controller.set("content", model);
  }

Is the default behavior, you don't need to define it.

Comment: Thanks Andre; I have tried both ways but neither of them change the result. As far I understand the underscore only affects how Ember does things by default if the `model` method isn't defined.

Comment: Did you ever find the solution to this one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[JSBin example](http://jsbin.com/adedag/105/edit)

You can structure your routes with a little bit more nesting to get the URLs you desire (and you don't need to have a return statement in your router):

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource("profile", function() {
    this.resource("userprofile", { path: '/:userId' }, function() {
      this.route("index", { path: '/' });
      this.route("activity", { path: '/activity' });
    });
  });
});
```

and then set up your routes like this:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return [Ember.Object.create({
      id: 1
    })];
   }
});

App.UserprofileIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    console.log("userindex route", params);
    return Ember.Object.create({
      id: 1
    });
  },
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    return controller.set("content", model);
  }
});

App.UserprofileActivityRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return Ember.Object.create({
      id: 1
    });
  },
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    return controller.set("content", model);
  }
});
```

You can link to the `/profile/1` page:

```
{{#linkTo userprofile.index user}}
```

or link to the `/profile/1/activity` page:

```
{{#linkTo userprofile.activity user}}
```