# Dynamic segment not working in ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

[Possible Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14752937/how-do-i-use-dynamic-segments-in-emberjs-2-2-router)

My code is quite simple, my html:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="sites">
<ul>
    {{#each controller}}
    <li>
        {{#linkTo 'sites.index' site}} {{siteName}} {{/linkTo}}
    </li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
</script>
```

My Ember code:

```
    WebApp.Router.map(function () {
    this.resource('sites', { path: '/' } , function() {
        this.route('index', { path: '/:site_id' })
    });
});


//returns all Sites to display
WebApp.SitesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
        return WebApp.Site.find();
    }
});



 WebApp.Site = DS.Model.extend({
      id: DS.attr('integer')
 });


WebApp.Site.FIXTURES = [
{
    id: 1,
    siteName: gff1.com
},
{        
    id: 2,
    siteName: gff2.com
},
{
    id: 3,
    siteName: gff3.com
}
];
```

I want to make a list of sites with link to `/sites/index/<ID>`
When I run this code I get `Assertion failed: Cannot call get with 'id' on an undefined object.`
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues going on here.  A working version can be found at http://jsbin.com/ikozuv/1/edit

The cause of your problem is in your template, you don't have site defined when you are trying to linkTo it.  This should fix that issue

```
{{#each site in controller}}
<li>
    {{#linkTo 'sites.index' site}} {{site.siteName}} {{/linkTo}}
</li>
{{/each}}
```

Note: the above still wouldn't be the preferred way to do it, see below.

The other issues include not listing siteName as an attribute to your WebApp.Site, setting an ID in your model declaration, and the url you are expecting `/sites/index/<ID>` isn't quite what you would get with the router defined the way it is.  The recommended way would be to configure your router like:

```
WebApp.Router.map(function () {
    this.resource('sites', { path: '/' } , function() {
        this.resource('site', { path: ':site_id' });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks man, yes the way you mentioned down is the way I've done it but I'm a new in ember so I didn't know if it is correct to write it like that. Why did you yous `this.resource('site', { path: ':site_id' })` instead of `this.route('site', { path: ':site_id' })`? it is working also with the `route`

Comment: "The rule of thumb is to use resources for nouns, and routes for adjectives (favorites) or verbs (edit)."  - http://emberjs.com/guides/concepts/naming-conventions/  It also makes routes cleaner for linkTo, eg. sites and site instead of sites and sites.site